# change QLineEdit input language

Tags: c++, qt

I want to force QLineEdit accepts input in another language. So I made a subclass. Is there any default way to convert key we pressed to another language key? (Like we changed language in our system)

```
class LocationInput : public QLineEdit
{
public:
    LocationInput (QLocale locate, QWidget *parent): QLineEdit(parent) {
       setLocale(locate);
    }

protected:
    void keyPressEvent ( QKeyEvent * event )
    {
        event->accept();
        QString coverted_key = "";//?
        QKeyEvent e(event->type(), event->key(), event->modifiers(), coverted_key);
        QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(&e);
    }
};
```

Comment: A german "t" is the same as an english "t" so I'm unsure what your question is.

Comment: @Goswin von Brederlow , for example, we pressed "t" in english, and german "t" locates in the same position on keybord, but in russian keyboard it is "е" latter. I want program prints "t" when QLocate is german or english and "e" if russian.

Comment: There is no such Qt solution, you should apply your keymap, push chars using the map and the virtual key.

Comment: @273K, Ok, thank you much. I understand how to do it, but I thought there was a Qt solution

Comment: Check your Desktop if it has a little app to change keyboards on the fly. They usually put a little flag in the systray you can click to change keyboard mappings. Some Desktops store a keyboard mapping per window. But ultimately the mapping should be the users choice. Also don't forget you can have a US keyboard with german translations. They are only loosely coupled.

Comment: @Goswin von Brederlow, I can change keyboard automatically, but I think it is not a really good solution.  In my application, user is entering a lot of words in 2 different languages, so I think it is better to user set them up once instead of pressing the shortcut every time.

Comment: Still not seeing the use case for what you ask for. I would be very annoyed if a QLineEdit would enter 'y' when I press 'z' because it know better than me what keyboard I have.

Comment: `QLineEdit` is not involved in translating keystrokes to characters. On Windows at least, the thread keyboard layout is responsible for this. To control it programmatically, see [`LoadKeyboardLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadkeyboardlayouta), [`ActivateKeyboardLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-activatekeyboardlayout) et al. I don't know of a platform-independent Qt wrapper for this functionality.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, ok, if it`s annoying for many users I will make it as an option, just for myself. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, probably better not to call system functions, but I will consider this option, thanks.